# Augmented Reality application on Android using Flash

Tags: android, air, flash-cs5, augmented-reality

I create an augmented reality application on android using the Adobe Flash Professional CS5 by following this video tutorial from Lee Brimelow(*http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=105*)

I wrote the program exactly as it shows on the video and it works correctly on my pc.
I then made the necessary changes to be able to publish it on my android nexus one mobile phone using Adobe Air for Android. 
I works correctly on my phone, however it is too slow and it crashes. Is there a way that I can make it work faster or do I need to make some specific modifications to what I have done?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try commenting out the marker detection routines, since those should be the most computationally intensive, to see how many FPS you get just capturing and rendering camera frames in AIR.  If that's slow, getting camera frames into AIR might be a bottleneck (and so you might have to abandon AIR).  If that's blisteringly fast, you might be able to optimize the marker detection routines for mobile somehow.  My gut feeling is mobile devices aren't yet fast enough to do vision-based AR in a runtime yet.  I don't really know anything about AIR specifically.

Comment: what do you mean by "commenting out the marker detection routines"?

Comment: @Apollon1954 I've just quickly scanned the demo, I don't want to give the impression I'm intimate with it in any way.  What I meant was to try running just the camera capture & rendering, without e.g. the FLARSingleMarkerDetector if possible, to see what framerate you get without the overhead of marker detection.  Another performance consideration is video-scaling, I guess you run your version for mobile at the phones' native resolution?